# How to handle evaluation of list of functions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, evaluation, tidy

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with custom aggregation function which will work with dplyr's evaluation principles. I'd like to create a function of a shape:

```
custom_aggregation <- function (data, stat_funs = list(mean, median), agg_col, ...)
```

where `data` is a data.frame, `stat_funs` is a list of functions to apply, `agg_col` indicates on which column the functions will be applied, `...` are grouping columns.

For a single aggreation function I use code like this:

```
custom_aggregation <- function (data, stat_fun, agg_col, ...) {

  groups <- enquos(...) 
  agg_col <- enquo(agg_col) 
  stat_fun_enq <- enquo(stat_fun) 
  agg_name <- paste0(quo_name(agg_col), '', quo_name(stat_fun_enq))

  data %>% 
    group_by(!!!groups) %>% 
    summarise(!!agg_name := stat_fun(!!agg_col)) 
}

# I can try to call the function on mtcars data.frame:
custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_fun = mean, agg_col = qsec, cyl, am)
```

I have no idea how to handle a list of function (`stat_fun` argument).

I tried:

```
map(stat_fun, enquo) # and the basic lapply equivalent with variants

lapply(stat_fun, function(i) {
  stat_fun_enq <- enquo(i)
})


lapply(seq_along(stat_fun), function(i) {
  stat_fun_enq <- enquo(stat_fun[[i]])
})
```

Can someone guide me with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be pass the functions as a quosure list and then `map` through the `list`, evaluate (`!!`) to apply the function

```
library(tidyverse)
custom_aggregation <- function (data, stat_fun, agg_col, ...) {

  groups <- enquos(...) 
  agg_col <- enquo(agg_col) 
  agg_name <- rlang::as_name(stat_fun)
  data %>%
        group_by(!!! groups) %>%
         summarise((!!agg_name) := (!!stat_fun)(!!agg_col))



}
```

Not clear about the expected output format

```
quos(mean, median)  %>%
      map(~ custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_fun = .x, agg_col = qsec, cyl, am))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    am  mean
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4     0  21.0
#2     4     1  18.4
#3     6     0  19.2
#4     6     1  16.3
#5     8     0  17.1
#6     8     1  14.6

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    am median
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     4     0   20.0
#2     4     1   18.6
#3     6     0   19.2
#4     6     1   16.5
#5     8     0   17.4
#6     8     1   14.6
```

#### Update

If we need in a single dataset

```
library(rlang)
custom_aggregation <- function (data, stat_fun, agg_col, ...) {

  groups <- enquos(...) 
  agg_col <- enquo(agg_col) 

  nm1 <- str_c(rlang::as_name(agg_col),
       map_chr(rlang::call_args(rlang::enexpr(stat_fun)),
             rlang::as_name), sep="_") 

  data %>%
         group_by(!!! groups) %>%
         summarise_at(vars(rlang::as_name(agg_col)), stat_fun) %>%
         rename_at(vars(starts_with('fn')), ~ nm1)





}
```

-testing

```
custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_fun = list(sum), agg_col = qsec, cyl, am)    # A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    am  qsec
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4     0  62.9
#2     4     1 148. 
#3     6     0  76.9
#4     6     1  49.0
#5     8     0 206. 
#6     8     1  29.1




custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_fun = list(sum, max), agg_col = qsec, cyl, am)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    am qsec_sum qsec_max
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     4     0     62.9     22.9
#2     4     1    148.      19.9
#3     6     0     76.9     20.2
#4     6     1     49.0     17.0
#5     8     0    206.      18  
#6     8     1     29.1     14.6


custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_fun = list(sum, min, max), agg_col = qsec, cyl, am)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    am qsec_sum qsec_min qsec_max
#  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1     4     0     62.9     20       22.9
#2     4     1    148.      16.7     19.9
#3     6     0     76.9     18.3     20.2
#4     6     1     49.0     15.5     17.0
#5     8     0    206.      15.4     18  
#6     8     1     29.1     14.5     14.6
```

Comment: Thanks. But the point is to call the function with `stat_funs = list(sum, max)` just like you do in dplyr. I've also found `alist` can be useful, but haven't tried yet.

Comment: @JakubMałecki  can u show your expected output.  Is it a list of data.frames or single data.frame.  Also, your preference of functions to use whether I can use `alist` or `enexpr` etc?

Comment: The preference is to use function names as they are, so no `'mean'` (i.e. character string) or `quos(mean)`, but `mean`. `alist` seems to be a good candidate. The output should be a single date.frame (not a list of data.frames). Calling `custom_aggregation` function this way ```custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_funs = list(sum, max), agg_col = qsec, cyl, am)``` will result ```# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl    am qsec_sum qsec_max```

Comment: ```structure(list(cyl = c(4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8), am = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1), qsec_sum = c(62.91, 147.6, 76.86, 48.98, 205.71, 29.1), 
    qsec_max = c(22.9, 19.9, 20.22, 17.02, 18, 14.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    cyl = c(4, 6, 8), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))```

Comment: Thank You very much, it's what I was looking for. The function breaks if I call it with `stat_fun = list(sum)`, i.e. there's only one function on the list, but I think I can handle it now.

Comment: @JakubMałecki  May be check the package versions.  For me, it is working fine `custom_aggregation(mtcars, stat_fun = list(sum), agg_col = qsec, cyl, am)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl    am  qsec
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     0  62.9
2     4     1 148. 
3     6     0  76.9
4     6     1  49.0
5     8     0 206. 
6     8     1  29.1`